# keras gradients computation fails "Invalid index from the dimension: 3, 0, C"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to compute the gradient of X w.r.t Y (doesn't really matter what X nor Y is) in a network with a conv1d layer I'm getting the message "Invalid index from the dimension: 3, 0, C" and the process dies.

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.keras import models
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

inp = layers.Input(shape=(10, 20,))
conv = layers.Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=2)(inp)
pool = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(conv)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(pool)

m = models.Model(inp, output)

m.summary()

m.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy")
```

Seems to work:

```
m.fit(x=np.random.randn(100, 10, 20), y=np.random.randn(100))
```

This breaks:

```
loss = K.mean(m.output)
grads = K.gradients(loss, m.input)[0]
f = K.function([m.input], [grads])
print(f([np.random.randn(10, 20)]))
```

My python, keras, tf versions:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from tensorflow.python import keras

print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)
print(sys.version)

1.12.0
2.1.6-tf
3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 14:01:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
```

It doesn't really matter of what I calculate the gradient wrt to what.. The error message is

```
2019-04-19 17:00:58.249788: F ./tensorflow/core/util/tensor_format.h:420] Check failed: index >= 0 && index < dimension_attributes.size() Invalid index from the dimension: 3, 0, C
```

I see that it is related to the conv 1d layer based on the error message, but I don't quite understand what I'm missing here. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I can't reproduce your question. My return error is `Invalid argument: transpose expects a vector of size 3. But input(1) is a vector of size 4` on `tensorflow=1.12.0` and `keras=2.1.6-tf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** shape incompatibility, change the call to: `f([np.random.randn(1, 10, 20)])`.

**Long answer:** Since you have set the input shape as `(10, 20,)`, it means that **each input sample** has a shape of `(10,20)`. However, you must also note that Keras models expect a **batch of samples** as their input. Therefore, in this case it would expect an array with 3 dimensions where the first dimension indicates the batch dimension. Since you want to feed the model with one sample, the input array must have a shape of `(1, 10, 20)`. So you must change the shape in `randn` function accordingly:

```
f([np.random.randn(1, 10, 20)])
                   ^
                   |
                   |
              batch dimension
```